# Android apps problems

Tags: java, android, xml, class, object

i have been trying to develop an app. But when i declare any object of say class Button or even any other Class then it says "Unfortunately the app has stopped" when i run it. Please Help.

The xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/timePicker1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
        android:text="Set" />

    <AnalogClock
        android:id="@+id/analogClock1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timePicker1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/analogClock1" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Main java file

package com.example.quiet;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
int hour;
int minute;
Button btn1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

The Log

```
   02-28 17:06:42.917: E/AndroidRuntime(18977): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.quiet/com.example.quiet.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TimePicker cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
02-28 17:06:42.917: E/AndroidRuntime(18977):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
02-28 17:06:42.917: E/AndroidRuntime(18977):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
02-28 17:06:42.917: E/AndroidRuntime(18977):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-28 17:06:42.917: E/AndroidRuntime(18977):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
02-28 17:06:42.917: E/AndroidRuntime(18977):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 17:06:42.917: E/AndroidRuntime(18977):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-28 17:06:42.917: E/AndroidRuntime(18977):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-28 17:06:42.917: E/AndroidRuntime(18977):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 17:06:42.917: E/AndroidRuntime(18977):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-28 17:06:42.917: E/AndroidRuntime(18977):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
02-28 17:06:42.917: E/AndroidRuntime(18977):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
02-28 17:06:42.917: E/AndroidRuntime(18977):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 17:06:42.917: E/AndroidRuntime(18977): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TimePicker cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
02-28 17:06:42.917: E/AndroidRuntime(18977):    at com.example.quiet.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
02-28 17:06:42.917: E/AndroidRuntime(18977):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
02-28 17:06:42.917: E/AndroidRuntime(18977):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-28 17:06:42.917: E/AndroidRuntime(18977):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
02-28 17:06:42.917: E/AndroidRuntime(18977):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: We really need your LogCat, but as a wild stab in the dark at the code you posted I'm gonna guess `btn1.setText(hour)` is finding a NullPointer on hour as it's value isn't defined, either that or if it is defined you need to have `btn1.setText(String.valueOf(hour));` to turn the int into a string

Comment: i used the same code..,its working..,what error you  are getting??

Comment: Have you declared your activity in Manifest?

Comment: `android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.TimePicker`. Line 22 of MainActivity.java. So I belive this isn't the complete code that you actually have which is in error.

Comment: i have removed everything just left the btn1 declaration ... still its not working

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's because of `btn1.setText(hour);`
Since hour is an int, setText will look for a resource with the ID you passed. Try passing a string to your setText.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `setText(0)` this causes exception instead call like something `setText("12:00")`;

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
btn1.setText("" + hour);
```

So to solve the int to string issue

Answer (score 0):

These lines look suspicious. (Disclaimer - this may or may not be the primary issue).

```
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/timePicker1"

    ....

    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timePicker1"
```

You are using the "@+id/" nomenclature for the layout relation. Remove the + sign such that you aren't trying to define an ID. Such as the following:

```
   android:layout_alignRight="@id/timePicker1"

    ....

   android:layout_alignLeft="@id/timePicker1"
```

Do however, keep the @+id/ tag for resource IDs on the widget they are being declared for:

```
<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
```

I'm not sure if the resource ID is your core problem, and the Android resource compiler can likely deal with it as you have it.  But it looked suspicious enough for me to call out.